# Creating an XPath Expression in SharePoint's "Add Formula Column" based on meta data

Tags: sharepoint, xpath, formula

OK,

So this is my first post to stack overflow, and I DID search and couldn't find exactly what I was looking for with regard to my question (although I might be terrible at searching). Essentially, this is my first pass at Xpath expressions and I honestly am having a tough time creating an if/else statement.

I have a DWVP that is displaying a list of documents from a document library on separate site. I have a column that notes whom a document is checked-out to (if it is checked-out), and if that document is checked out, I have conditional formatting that will highlight the row.

All is well so far. I have a list of documents that have a bunch of meta data and one or two of the rows in this list is highlighted yellow because they are checked-out, and the users name is listed in the "@checkedouttouser" column.

My issue is that I want to create another column (I'm assuming a formula column) within this DVWP that will display a link to the source document library (specifically with a view enabled that filters the content to "checked out to" [ME], but that's no issue) if the column "@checkedouttouser" has anything in it.

My thought process here is that this new formula column will check to see if *anything* is written (or alternatively *not* written) in this column, and if so it will create a link that says "Check-In this Document". So if you look at the DVWP, you will see a yellow row that indicates that the document has been checked out, and since it is yellow and since it is checked out, the right-hand most formula column will show a link that says "Check-In this Document".

I have never written an Xpath expression before, but got *somewhere* with the following expression:

if /@CheckedoutToUser!=" ",

I have a feeling it will start something like that?

What would this expression look like?!

Comment: I didn't quite understand you - did you try using a calculated column? Something like this: `IF(NOT(ISBLANK([CheckedOut])), "Success", "Failure")` - where are you using XPath?

Comment: The reason I was adding an XPath expression was so I did not need to add a calculated columnn to the source list. But now that I think about, I could add a calculated column, hide it from view, hide it from the newitem and edititem forms, and just display it in the DVWP, no?

That being said. How can I expand this formula so when I get a failure, it creates a hyperlink? i.e. - failure will show up as a hyperlink that links to the source library?

Comment: Try including your xslt and the xml.

Comment: This isn't an XSLT question at all -- retagged. Also, you do not explain exactly which nodes you want the XPath expression to select. Please edit your question so that it becomes a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not quite sure what you want to do, a little bit of the xslt and the xml would help

```
<xsl:if test="@CheckedOutToUser"><span>add extra content<span></xsl:if>
```

If you need to display the underlying xml from your page, the deprecated tag

`<xmp><xsl:copy-of select="." /></xmp>`

will do the trick.